# How to install HP Laserjet Professional M1136 Printer on Ubuntu 16.02

Tags: software-installation, printing, hp

I don't know how to install this printer on Ubuntu 16.02. I am a beginner and don't know anything about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Unity (which is the default GUI), you can do this:

1. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for System Settings.
2. Navigate to Printers and click "Add".
3. Click and follow the onscreen instructions. Many HP printers can be detected out of the box. My HP deskjet 4515 was detected very easily.

Also try HP's support site and looking for ppd files. These can hold the config settings that are required to support the printer. HP has usually had good support for Linux.